# SAS : How to iterate a dataset elements within the proc sql WHERE statement?

Tags: sas

I need to create multiple tables using `proc sql`

```
   proc sql;

   /* first city */
   create table London as 
   select * from connection to myDatabase 
   (select * from mainTable 
    where city = 'London'); 

   /* second city */
   create table Beijing as 
   select * from connection to myDatabase 
   (select * from mainTable 
    where city = 'Beijing');

   /* . .  the same thing for other cities */

   quit;
```

The names of those cities are in the sas table `myCities`

How can I embed the `data` step into `proc sql` in order to iterate through all cities ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that requires a separate dataset per city? A lot of the time it's simpler to keep everything  in one big dataset.

Comment: I am backing up a database. I just tried to put it in a simple language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively simple solution to this is to do this entirely *in* a data step.  Assuming you can connect via libname (which if you can connect via `connect to` you probably can), let's say the libname is `mydb`.  Using a similar construction to Max Power's for the first portion:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select city_varname 
    into :citylist separated by ' ' 
    from myCities;
  select cats('%when(var=',city_varname,')') 
    into :whenlist separated by ' '
    from myCities;
quit; 

%macro when(var=);
  when "&var." output &var.;
%mend when;


data &citylist.;
  set mydb.mainTable;
  select(city);
    &whenlist.;
    otherwise;
  end;
run;
```

If you're using most of the data in mainTable, this probably wouldn't be much slower than doing it database-side, as you're moving all of the data anyway - and likely it would be faster since you only hit the database once.

Even better would be to pull this to one table (like Max shows), but this is a reasonable method if you do need to create multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
proc sql noprint;
select quote(city_varname) into :cities separated by ',' from myCities;
quit;
```

*This step above creates a list as a macro variable to be used with the in() operator below. EDIT: Per Joe's comment, added quote() function so that each city will go into the macro-var list within quotes, for proper referencing by in() operator below.

```
create table all_cities as 
select * from connection to myDatabase 
(select * from mainTable 
where city in (&cities));
```

*this step is just the step you provided in your question, slightly modified to use in() with the macro-variable list defined above.

Comment: You should use `quote()` to add the quotes (since they almost certainly don't have quotes).

Comment: This is exactly what i have been doing previously. (+1  :))  However, the problem with this approach is : I have too many cities (>3000) and one macro variable is not able to hold such a long string

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to put your proc sql code into a SAS Macro.
2. Create a macro-variable for City (in my example I called the macro-variable "City").
3. Execute the macro from a datastep program.  Since the Datastep program processes one for each observation, there is no need to create complex logic to iterate.

   ```
   data mycities;
       infile datalines dsd;
       input macrocity $ 32.;
       datalines;
   London
   Beijing
   Buenos_Aires
   ;
   run;

   %macro createtablecity(city=);
   proc sql;
      /* all cities  */
      create table &city. as 
      select * from connection to myDatabase 
      (select * from mainTable 
       where city = "&city.");
   quit; 
   %mend;

   data _null_;
       set mycities;
       city = macrocity;
       call execute('%createtablecity('||city||')');
   run;
   ```

Comment: Your use of symput and &city here doesn't really make sense.  Why are you not using the parameter `&macrocity` (or calling that `city` and skipping the rest of this business)?

Comment: You are right, I am being redundant. I was just trying to explain clearly that by understanding datastep processing, the role of the PDV and how it gets populated, he will be able to iterate through his original dataset containing the cities.  I was redundant because I wrote the code from top of my head.  I cannot even test it since he is using a passthrough and a select statement pointing to who knows what.

Comment: I don't think you're being redundant, I think your code probably wouldn't work, and at best is really confusing.  I don't believe the macro variable timing works as you suggest.

Comment: Hmm, I take that back as far as timing; a quick test verifies the timing does work.  I still object to the concept of defining a global macro variable for this purpose, though.

Comment: I tried executing it in EG.  I took out macrocity from the macro declaration and from the macro call, and it worked. I think you were right there.

Comment: Btw, I wouldn't worry about including connect to... and such in answers like this; show an example that works with `sashelp.class` or whatever.  Examples should be runnable whenever possible, and if OP can't figure out how to adapt, can ask separately :)

Comment: What I'd do:  ``
%macro createtablename(name=);
proc sql;
  create table &name. as 
   select * from sashelp.class
    where name = "&name.";
quit; 
%mend;

data _null_;
    set sashelp.class;
    call execute('%createtablename(name='||name||')');
run;``

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other solutions here really, maybe a bit simpler... Pull out a distinct list of cities, place into macros, run SQL query within a do loop.

```
Proc sql noprint;
  Select distinct city, count(city) as c
  Into :n1-:n999, :c
  From connection to mydb
  (Select *
   From mainTable)
;
 Quit;

%macro createTables;

%do a=1 %to &c;

Proc sql;
  Create table &&n&a as
  Select  *
  From connection to myDb
  (Select *
   From mainTable
   Where city="&&n&a")
;
 Quit;

%end;

%mend createTables;

%createTables;
```